# Android Firebase Database - Retrieving data sorted by timestamp

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing an Android app that uses Firebase database. To use the app, the user has to create an account and log-in. I save the account info in Firebase Database.

[image]

The app is retrieving the user list from Firebase. How can I retrieve the user lists by the time they joined (sorted by the timestamp)? I tried this:

```
    DatabaseReference firebaseAskRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constants.FIREBASE_LOCATION_ASKS_LIST);
    Query query = firebaseAskRef.orderByChild("timestampPosted/timestamp");
    adapter= new UserAdapter(getActivity(), User.class,R.layout.ask_item, ViewHolder.class,query);
```

But it's not working. Could you give any suggestions?

Comment: I think it would be easier if you store your timestamp on "timestampJoined" node, not adding child node again. If you do that, you can easily sort it by this : `firebaseAskRef.orderByChild("timestampJoined");`

Comment: And in your database it is "timestampJoined" but in your code it is "timestampPosted" did you mistype that? or it is from different part of your application?